# Can I combine multiple IncrementalValuesProvider<T> into an object that makes sense?

Tags: roslyn

I want to combine multiple `IncrementalValuesProvider<T>`

I don't find `var result = a.Combine(b.Combine(c));` very appealing, because `result.Left.Left` and `result.Right.Left` etc are not intuitive at all.

Is there some way I can combine multiple `IncrementalValuesProvider<T>` into a single custom object? For example

```cs
  IncrementalValuesProvider<One> one = ...;
  IncrementalValuesProvider<Two> two = ...;
  IncrementalValuesProvider<Three> three = ...;

  IncrementalValuesProvider<Combined> = one.Combine(two.Collect())
    .Select(x => new { One = x.Left, Two = x.Right })
    .Combine(three.Collect())
    .Select(x => new Combined {
      One = x.Left.One,
      Two = x.Left.Two,
      Three = x.Right
    });
```

Absolutely anything will do as long as I don't have to keep traversing left/left/right/left :)

Comment: Note: you need to be very careful when combining providers, as it ties the incrementality of each one together. That is, as soon as one of the providers changes, any code which depends on the combined ones will have to re-run.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That's exactly what I need to happen :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to convert `IncrementalValuesProvider` (plural) to `IncrementalValueProvider` (single).

`IncrementalValueProvider<ImmutableArray<one>> newOne = one.Collect();`

Then you can do this

```cs
var oneAndTwo = one.Combine(two)
  .Select((x, cancellationToken) => new 
  {
    One = x.Left,
    Two = x.Right

IncrementalValueProvider<OneAndTwoAndThree> oneAndTwoAndThree = oneAndTwo.Combine(three)
  .Select((x, cancellationToken) => new OneAndTwoAndThree(
    x.Left.One,
    x.Left.Two,
    x.Right);
```